# How to enable autologin on a raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3

Please don't tell me to configure it in raspi-config. I have absolutely no options there to do it. asda sdsdf sdfsadc fsdfasd f fasdf cxwasef casefc asewfxx asfx asef ase cfs x

Comment: Not sure if this should be flagged as spam or duplicate.. please do not speak in tongues and give more background to your problem. Otherwise google this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may have not updated your system yet, please do. The autologin option should exist.

Googling `raspberry pi autologin manually` took me to a related questions. You can do that too. The correct configuration file to enter the autologin username may vary depending on what you mean (autologin on CLI or into desktop, what exact raspberry you have, etc.).

It also talks about raspi-config (maybe read it more carefully one more time and update your system beforehand?).

Possible duplicate: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40415/how-to-enable-auto-login

The [bottom answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58737) has a suggestion for a configuration file to enter the username. You may find something similar on your system, if that exists.